# Color mismatch using rgl

Tags: r, rgl

I am using rgl to create a scatterplot of points from an imported .csv dataset.  The colors that I'd like the points to be is set in the dataset.  Everything works fine, except that when the scatterplot is displayed the colors of the points do not match the colors defined in the data.  E.g., all the points that are designated as "blue" might actually be green, and all the points designated as "yellow" might actually show up red.

```
data=read.csv("ExpLayout.csv", header = TRUE)
x=data$x
y=data$y
z=data$z
color=data$color
plot3d(x=x, y=y, z=z, type="s", col=color)
```

Comment: Try reading in your data with `read.csv(filename, header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`, then report back.

Comment: And if Marius' suggestion doesn't work try pasting some of your data via `dput( head( data ) )`

Comment: @user2163189: You may see the colour names showing up like `"red"`, but that doesn't mean that `color` is actually a `character` vector and not a `factor`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is almost certainly due to `read.csv` converting strings to factors

See the difference in this reproducible example

```
library(rgl)
x<-1:5
y=1:5
z <- 1:5
colors <- c('red','green','blue','orange','purple')
plot3d(x=x,y=y,z=z,col=colors, type = 's')
colorsf <- factor(c('red','green','blue','orange','purple'))
plot3d(x=x,y=y,z=z,col=colorsf, type = 's')
```

So, either read in `color` as a character column using `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` or coerce to character using `as.character()` or `levels(colors)[colors]`

Comment: That did it! I had put the colors into the data set within "" under the assumption that would allow them to be treated as strings, but apparently that doesn't quite cut it.  Thank you mnel and @Marius !

Comment: this was very helpful, thanks. I've been using R for awhile now and I am still tripped up by things like this.